# The sum of an image array is different from that of the same image array after write&read

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I read an image using

`img1 = cv2.imread('xxx.jpg')`

and counted the array sum

`sum1 = img1.sum()`

Then I saved the image array and read it again like

```
cv2.imwrite('test2.jpg', img1)
img2 = cv2.imread('test2.jpg')
```

and counted the sum like

```
sum2 = img2.sum()
```

I expected that `sum1 == sum2` is `True`, but the fact is not.

Why?

Comment: You're reading a bitmap from a .jpg, then saving the bitmap as .jpg, and then reading a bitmap from the resulting .jpg file - but .jpg is a lossy format, so I would expect that to be the reason.

Comment: As Grismar said, .jpg is a lossy format. If you want to keep the original, `imwrite` it as .png or .bmp file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the comments.

> You're reading a bitmap from a .jpg, then saving the bitmap as .jpg,
> and then reading a bitmap from the resulting .jpg file - but .jpg is a
> lossy format, so I would expect that to be the reason.